# glm polynomial regression, sacrifice fit for value at zero

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

I have data that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    y = c(0.348, 0.099, 0.041, 0.022, 0.015, 0.010, 0.007, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003),
    x = c(458, 648, 694, 724, 756, 790, 818, 836, 848, 876))
```

My (simplified) regression model is sort of like this:

```
m1 <- glm(y ~ poly(x, 2), data = df)
df$predict <- predict(m1, df)
df
#        y   x     predict
# 1  0.348 458 0.349095453
# 2  0.099 648 0.086238941
# 3  0.041 694 0.049501859
# 4  0.022 724 0.031192879
# 5  0.015 756 0.016579779
# 6  0.010 790 0.006614136
# 7  0.007 818 0.002709055
# 8  0.005 836 0.002250483
# 9  0.004 848 0.002836871
# 10 0.003 876 0.006980543
```

And here's a graph of the fit:

[image]

It fits pretty good. Except... looking at values at row 9 and 10... they're higher than the value at row 8. (Duh... it's a quadratic!). But I know those values are clearly wrong.

How can I sacrifice a little bit of fit in order force my quadratic to pass through a value... like (900, 0)?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you assume a quadratic relationship and not some kind of non-linear model? What is the purpose of modelling this? What do you know about the process that generated this data? You can always fit a non-parametric model (`loess` , `mgcv::gam`, ...).

Comment: And of course, you can tune your quadratic model using weights (but I really don't see a quadratic relationship there).

Comment: Just to illustrate my point that a non-linear model (with the same number of parameters) could fit better: `fit <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, a, m, s), data = df, weights = 1/df$y); plot(y ~ x, data = df); curve(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = x)), add = TRUE)`. However, you need a justification from science for using a non-linear model.

Comment: And here is non-parametric fit: `fit <- loess(y ~ x, span = 0.8, data = df, weights = 1/df$y); plot(y ~ x, data = df); curve(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = x)), add = TRUE)`. You'd need to use, e.g., cross-validation to optimize the degree of smoothing.